# How to deploy from Visual Studio to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, webdeploy

I set up an Azure site years ago and have been making only small changes since, but I've upgraded my PC and now Visual Studio no longer remembers the credentials to deploy the site.

I went into the Azure portal but everything is different now and much more complicated. How do I set up credentials to use webdeploy in the new interface?

Comment: Sign in with your credentials on visual studio-> Right click on Project and select Publish -> Select Microsoft Azure App Service -> Select existing and then select your subscription , resource group name and web app name

Answer (score 0):

If you sign in to visual studio using your azure AD credentials then you can easily deploy web app to azure.
Considering you are signed in to visual studio using your azure credentials then you can go to View->Cloud explorer
You should be able to see available subscriptions here

[image]